# Access Formik bag in Wizard using useFormik hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm following a multistep wizard form example provided [by Formik](https://github.com/formium/formik/blob/master/examples/MultistepWizard.js). I am trying to configure it in a way so I can access [formik bag](https://formik.org/docs/api/withFormik#the-formikbag). I need to be able to use `setFieldValue` in one of the `<Field/>` components to handle an event change inside `AppContainer`.

I have a [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-grass-guq0o?file=/src/App.js) with my current code, it can be found below as well.

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useContext,
  createContext,
  useMemo,
  useEffect
} from "react";
import {
  ErrorMessage,
  Field,
  Form,
  Formik,
  useFormik,
  FormikProvider,
  FormikConsumer
} from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { Debug } from "./Debug";

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

// Wizard is a single Formik instance whose children are each page of the
// multi-step form. The form is submitted on each forward transition (can only
// progress with valid input), whereas a backwards step is allowed with
// incomplete data. A snapshot of form state is used as initialValues after each
// transition. Each page has an optional submit handler, and the top-level
// submit is called when the final page is submitted.
const Wizard = ({ children, initialValues, onSubmit }) => {
  const [stepNumber, setStepNumber] = useState(0);
  const steps = React.Children.toArray(children);
  const [snapshot, setSnapshot] = useState(initialValues);

  const step = steps[stepNumber];
  const totalSteps = steps.length;
  const isLastStep = stepNumber === totalSteps - 1;

  const next = (values) => {
    setSnapshot(values);
    setStepNumber(Math.min(stepNumber + 1, totalSteps - 1));
  };

  const previous = (values) => {
    setSnapshot(values);
    setStepNumber(Math.max(stepNumber - 1, 0));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (values, bag) => {
    if (step.props.onSubmit) {
      await step.props.onSubmit(values, bag);
    }
    if (isLastStep) {
      return onSubmit(values, bag);
    } else {
      bag.setTouched({});
      next(values);
    }
  };

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: snapshot,
    onSubmit: handleSubmit,
    validationSchema: step.props.validationSchema
  });

  return (
    <>
      <FormikProvider value={formik}>
        <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
          <p>
            Step {stepNumber + 1} of {totalSteps}
          </p>
          {step}
          <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            {stepNumber > 0 && (
              <button onClick={() => previous(formik.values)} type="button">
                Back
              </button>
            )}
            <div>
              <button disabled={formik.isSubmitting} type="submit">
                {isLastStep ? "Submit" : "Next"}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Debug />
        </form>
      </FormikProvider>
    </>
  );
};

const WizardStep = ({ children }) => children;

const AppContainer = (props) => {
  const [wizardState, setWizardState] = useWizardContext();

  return (
    <Wizard
      initialValues={{
        email: "",
        firstName: "",
        lastName: ""
      }}
      onSubmit={async (values) =>
        sleep(300).then(() => console.log("Wizard submit", values))
      }
    >
      <WizardStep
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          setWizardState(values);
          console.log("Step1 onSubmit");
        }}
        validationSchema={Yup.object({
          firstName: Yup.string().required("required"),
          lastName: Yup.string().required("required")
        })}
      >
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
          <Field
            autoComplete="given-name"
            component="input"
            id="firstName"
            name="firstName"
            placeholder="First Name"
            type="text"
            // onChange={(e) => {
            //   formik.setFieldValue("firstName", "firstName22");
            // }}
          />
          <ErrorMessage className="error" component="div" name="firstName" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <Field
            autoComplete="family-name"
            component="input"
            id="lastName"
            name="lastName"
            placeholder="Last Name"
            type="text"
          />
          <ErrorMessage className="error" component="div" name="lastName" />
        </div>
      </WizardStep>
      <WizardStep
        onSubmit={() => {
          console.log(wizardState);
          console.log("Step2 onSubmit");
        }}
        validationSchema={Yup.object({
          email: Yup.string()
            .email("Invalid email address")
            .required("required")
        })}
      >
        <div>
          <div>
            How can I get access to formik helpers here, like setFielValue..
            etc?
          </div>
          <div> fisrtName from context: {wizardState.firstName} </div>
          <div> lastName from context: {wizardState.lastName} </div>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <Field
            autoComplete="email"
            component="input"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            type="text"
          />
          <ErrorMessage className="error" component="div" name="email" />
        </div>
      </WizardStep>
    </Wizard>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Formik Multistep Wizard</h1>
    <WizardProvider>
      <AppContainer />
    </WizardProvider>
  </div>
);

export default App;

const WizardContext = createContext();

const WizardProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [wizardState, setWizardState] = useState({});

  const value = useMemo(() => [wizardState, setWizardState], [
    wizardState,
    setWizardState
  ]);

  return (
    <WizardContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</WizardContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useWizardContext = () => useContext(WizardContext);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can access the whole bag:

```js
const form = useFormikContext()
form.setFieldValue(name, value)
```

Or for individual fields:

```js
const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(name)
helpers.setValue(value)
```

Comment: Can you provide some more context?

Comment: Sorry, was typing in a rush

Comment: I'm still getting `setFieldValue` undefined. Can you edit the codesandbox to show this?

Comment: I don't have a `<Formik />` component in my tree

Comment: I have updated my codesandbox example with the error I'm getting when using `setFieldValue`

Comment: Well I don't know why you did it like this, but why don't you replace `useFormik()` and the provider with `<Formik>`?

Answer (score 2):

So I found a solution for my issue. Using children in a callback function. Formik [docs here](https://formik.org/docs/api/field#children). When trying to use `useFormikContext()` I was making a mistake by mixing formik contexts.

The [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-grass-guq0o?file=/src/App.js) is updated with the working changes.

So using a callback function I achieved my desired outcome

```
      <Field component="select" name="firstName" id="firstName">
        {({ field, form: { isSubmitting } }) => (
          <select
            {...field}
            onChange={(e) => {
              console.log("side effect");
              field.onChange(e);
            }}
            disabled={isSubmitting}
          >
            <option value="">Select Name</option>
            {list.map(({ name, i }, index) => {
              return (
                <React.Fragment key={index}>
                  <option value={`${name}`}>{name}</option>
                </React.Fragment>
              );
            })}
          </select>
        )}
      </Field>
```